# SQL Server: From weekly sums to average of weekly periods

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have daily production data that I group into weekly data as follows:

```
declare @rundate datetime = '2019-04-22'

select 
    convert(date, max (usedate)) as recorddate, 
    DATEDIFF(d, usedate, @rundate)/7 as weeks_ago, 
    sum(usecount) as usecountsum
from 
    usagetable
where 
    usedate <> @rundate and
    DATEDIFF(d, usedate, @rundate) >= 0 
group by 
    DATEDIFF(d, usedate, @rundate)/7
order by 
    weeks_ago asc
```

Can anyone suggest efficient way(s) to get another table from above with the following column headers that should be self-explanatory:

```
recorddate  mostrecentweek      weeklyavglast4weeks weeklyavglast26weeks    weeklyavglast52weeks
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I went with finally:

```
declare @rundate datetime = '2019-04-22'

;with grp as (
select 
    convert(date, max (usedate)) as recorddate, 
    DATEDIFF(d, usedate, @rundate)/7 as weeks_ago, 
    sum(usecount) as usecountsum
from 
    usagetable
where 
    usedate <> @rundate and
    DATEDIFF(d, usedate, @rundate) >= 0 
group by 
    DATEDIFF(d, usedate, @rundate)/7
order by 
    weeks_ago asc )
select 
        usedate, 
        usecount as LastWk,  
        avg(usecount) OVER (ORDER BY usedate desc  ROWS BETWEEN 0 PRECEDING AND 3 FOLLOWING) as FourWkMA,
        avg(usecount) OVER (ORDER BY usedate desc  ROWS BETWEEN 0 PRECEDING AND 25 FOLLOWING) as TwentySixWkMA,
        avg(usecount) OVER (ORDER BY usedate desc ROWS BETWEEN 0 PRECEDING AND 51 FOLLOWING) as FiftyTwoWkMA
    from 
        grp
    order by 
        usedate desc
```